# How can I make sure that Async task is only calling once

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a method which has a async task and it is called from several different services and those services runs periodically . I want to make sure when one task is on going , no other thing can call it unless the task is finished.

```
public class Helper {

    public static void doSomethingAsync() {
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
                //doing something
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer resultCode) {

            }
        }.execute();
    }

    public static void someOtherMethod(){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`AsyncTask.getStatus()` will give the status of the task, i.e. whether finished or not.

Declare a member variable

```
private static AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer> mTask;
```

Modify your method as,

```
public static void doSomethingAsync() {

    if(null != mTask && mTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED){
       return; //Returning as the current task execution  is not finished yet.
    }

    mTask = new AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
            //doing something
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer resultCode) {

        }
    };
    mTask.execute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your solution, but it is crashing . It gives me `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object[] cannot be cast to java.lang.String[]`  in `private static AsyncTask mTask` this line

Comment: I have corrected my answer. The declaration should be AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>. Please try with this changes

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all your services has access to same [Mutex](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140767.html) which can be accesses throughout your application.

Now before accessing the Async Task, do as follows

```
public class Mutex {
   public void acquire() throws InterruptedException { }
   public void release() { }
   public boolean attempt(long msec) throws InterruptedException { }
}
```

Which then can be used as:

```
try {
  mutex.acquire();
  try {
    // do something
  } finally {
    mutex.release();
  }
} catch(InterruptedException ie) {
  // ...
}
```

Check out more details over [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html)

---

In Android we have [Semaphore](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html). For which the following will be the steps

```
java.util.concurrent.Semaphore semaphore=new Semaphore(1);

boolean isAvailable = semaphore.tryAcquire();
if(isAvailable){
    // Access AsyncTask
}
```

Once all actions are done, till onPostExecute

```
 semaphore.release();
```

Comment: Thanks , an alternative approach , I will give it a try .

Answer (score 2):

You can try this by making your **"doSomethingAsync()"** as **synchronized** method.

```
public synchronized static void doSomethingAsync() {
        new AsyncTask<String, Void, Integer>() {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
            }

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(String... strings) {
                //doing something
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer resultCode) {
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Note:

**static synchronized method** will lock the class instead of the object, and it will lock the class because the keyword static means: "**class instead of instance**". The keyword synchronized means that only one thread can access the method at a time.
And together they mean: "Only one can access class at one time".

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have edited my question. As you can see I have several method in that class. As you said `Only one can access class at one time` , so my question is will this make other method in that class inaccessible , while the async task is executing ?

Comment: @mSapps : Other methods in that class can be accessed by any no. of times from where ever you want and "doSomethingAsync()" will not going to block anything to access.

Comment: Suppose 2 service are running. Service1 gets a chance to access doSomethingAsync() method and in mean time service2 tries to calls doSomethingAsync() it wont access as lock is already acquired by service 1 thread. And when service1 release that lock there after service 2 gets a chance to access doSomethingAsync() again. Hope it make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an IntentService instead as this supports queuing and runs in a background thread

Answer (score 0):

You should refer Synchronization concept, it will help u.
[Link](http://Synchronization%20in%20Java%20-%20javatpoint)